# \flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\settings.gradle.kts:1:1: Unresolved reference: dependencyResolutionManagement

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I installed flutter and dart, on windows the project starts and works normally, but when trying to build and run it under android 8 gradle errors. FLutter doctor shows no errors.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX3363 in debug mode...
e: D:\Programs\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\settings.gradle.kts:1:1: Unresolved reference: dependencyResolutionManagement
e: D:\Programs\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\settings.gradle.kts:1:1: Cannot access implicit script receiver class 'org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
e: D:\Programs\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\settings.gradle.kts:2:3: Unresolved reference: repositoriesMode
e: D:\Programs\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\settings.gradle.kts:2:24: Unresolved reference: RepositoriesMode
e: D:\Programs\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\settings.gradle.kts:3:3: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun Project.repositories(configuration: RepositoryHandler.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public fun ScriptHandler.repositories(configuration: RepositoryHandler.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
e: D:\Programs\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\settings.gradle.kts:4:5: Unresolved reference: google
e: D:\Programs\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\settings.gradle.kts:5:5: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun RepositoryHandler.mavenCentral(vararg args: Pair<String, Any?>): MavenArtifactRepository defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.CompiledKotlinSettingsScript, unresolved supertypes: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware
    class org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.DefaultKotlinScript, unresolved supertypes: org.gradle.internal.scripts.GradleScript
Adding -Xextended-compiler-checks argument might provide additional information.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'D:\Programs\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\settings.gradle.kts' line: 1

* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 1: dependencyResolutionManagement {
          ^ Unresolved reference: dependencyResolutionManagement

  Line 1: dependencyResolutionManagement {
          ^ Cannot access implicit script receiver class 'org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

  Line 2:   repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)
            ^ Unresolved reference: repositoriesMode

  Line 2:   repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)
                                 ^ Unresolved reference: RepositoriesMode

  Line 3:   repositories {
            ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
                public fun Project.repositories(configuration: RepositoryHandler.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                public fun ScriptHandler.repositories(configuration: RepositoryHandler.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

  Line 4:     google()
              ^ Unresolved reference: google

  Line 5:     mavenCentral()
              ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
                  public inline fun RepositoryHandler.mavenCentral(vararg args: Pair<String, Any?>): MavenArtifactRepository defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

  Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
      class org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.CompiledKotlinSettingsScript, unresolved supertypes: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware
      class org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.DefaultKotlinScript, unresolved supertypes: org.gradle.internal.scripts.GradleScript
  Adding -Xextended-compiler-checks argument might provide additional information.

8 errors

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).
```

Install old version of android studio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You want me to provide the code for what? What file?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. So far, I've tried upgrade to 3.16.5, downgrade to 3.13.9, Invalidate caches, changed, jdk/jre (21, 17 etc), with Android Studio, with VS Code, and Clean install after removing everything android and flutter related, on my Windows 11 laptop. The new flutter projects won't build. The setup was working fine previously (3-4 months back). I didn't try flutter in last some months. I just upgraded the flutter to latest one, last week. I don't remember what was the exact version, but it was probably 3.13.x.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to tell exactly what's the problem, but this looks suspicious:

> Install old version of android studio

Why would you that?

Anyway, the "Unresolved reference" errors you're experiencing are likely caused by using a version of Gradle that's too old. For example, if you look at [dependenciesResolutionManagement](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/resolve/DependencyResolutionManagement.html) docs page, you'll see it's available since Gradle 6.8 – make sure you're using that or newer version. See also [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/137886#issuecomment-1793852741) for guidance on how to update Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

The problem is that I get the message that there is no Properties class.